# Integration in C^* algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a C${}^*$ algebra and $\mathbb{R}\ni s \mapsto \alpha_s$ a continuous family of its automorphisms. Is it true that

$$
\int d s \, f(s)\, \alpha_s(A)
$$

is well defined as a Bochner integral for any $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What continuity/measurability conditions are you putting on the map $s\mapsto \alpha_s$? You might want to look up the Pettis measurability theorem

Comment: OK, now if you have continuity in some kind of SOT for the family $(\alpha_s)$ then I think the Pettis measurability theorem should do the job.

Comment: Alternatively, this feels like the kind of thing that might be discussed in Kadison+Ringrose when they need to introduce some form of modular theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

$\alpha_s(A)$ is a continuous bounded function.

The function
$f(s) \alpha_s(A)$ is measurable and because of

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \|f(s) \alpha_s(A)\| ds \le \int_\mathbb{R} |f(s)| ds\, \|A\| < \infty$$

in $L^1$.

Quite elementary, look in the book "Serge Lang, Real and Functional Analysis", Chapter Integration for related things.

Comment: [deleted comment which was based on a hasty misreading]